# fom submit after preventDefault() when using react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

What am doing here is on clicking a link verify if all fields are filled if filled submit form as usual else will show some errors. But how can I continue submiting a form normally after using `e.preventdefault` in react?

```
var formComponent = React.createClass({
verifyFields: function (e) {
e.preventDefault();
    if (this.state.primaryGuestName && this.state.primaryGuestMobile) {
       // how can i continue with form submission here(not using xhr)
    } else {
        showErrors();
    }
},

render: function () {
<form action={this.props.action} ref="booking_form" acceptCharset="UTF-8" method="post">
    {form contents}
    <a href="" name="submit_details" onClick={this.verifyFields}
                           className="btn-flat btn-large rd-button">Confirm Details</a>
 </form>
}
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To submit the form explicitly you need to call the `submit()` method

Your verifyFields function would become something like this.

```
verifyFields: function (e) {
e.preventDefault();
    if (this.state.primaryGuestName && this.state.primaryGuestMobile) {
       // how can i continue with form submission here(not using xhr)
        document.getElementById('myForm').submit();
    } else {
        showErrors();
    }
},
```

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't really query the dom for the form, instead use the `onSubmit` event and a button then the implementation is a lot cleaner:

```
var formComponent = React.createClass({
    submit: function(e) {
        if (!this.verifyFields()) {
            e.preventDefault();
            showErrors();
            return false;
        }

        // continue here..
        return true;
    },

    verifyFields: function () {
        return this.state.primaryGuestName && this.state.primaryGuestMobile;
    },

    render: function () {
        return (
            <form action={this.props.action} onSubmit={this.submit} acceptCharset="UTF-8" method="post">
                {form contents}
                <button type="submit" className="btn-flat btn-large rd-button">Confirm Details</button>
            </form>
        );
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Call `submit` on the form.

```
e.preventDefault();
    if (this.state.primaryGuestName && this.state.primaryGuestMobile) {
       e.target.submit();
    } else {
        showErrors();
    }
}
```

Comment: this wont work as it throws undefined function submit()

Comment: You're right.  I misread you're code as the event being on the form.